# Real Roots of Cubic equation

Tags: equation-solving

If I have the cubic equation, how can i find the real root of x ? I try this but i get complex root

```
Solve[b (q - 1)*(x^3) + (m - s)*(x^2) + (a - n)*x + v == 0, x]
```

where b,q,m,s,a,n,v are nonnative parameters

I apprciate for help

Comment: Do you want to know the conditions on the parameters that make all roots real? It's `Discriminant[cubic, x] >= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce[b (q - 1)*(x^3) + (m - s)*(x^2) + (a - n)*x + v == 0, x, Reals]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and many many more ...

Comment: So what your answer is supposed to demonstrate? This is not even an explicit form---you have `Root` object. And why is there so many roots?

Comment: @yarchik Adding the parameter constraints can help though: `Reduce[Flatten[{b (q - 1)*(x^3) + (m - s)*(x^2) + (a - n)*x + v == 0, 
   Map[# > 0 &, {b, q, m, s, a, n, v}]}], x, Reals]`